# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I try to calculate word frequency and sort the frequency from big to small 
but face the above list object has no attribute key problem

I think result is really a dic so how can it has not "key"？
thanks.

```
#encoding=utf-8
import os


result = {}
if os.path.exists("test.txt"):
    day_file = open("test.txt").read()
    day_file_list = day_file.split(" ")

    for i in day_file_list:
                #   print "i： s" + str(i) + "e"
        if i == "#" or " ":
            day_file_list.remove(i)
                        #continue
            if i not in result:
                result[i] = 1  
            else:
                result[i] = result[i] + 1
                #   print "result i: " + str(result[i])

result = sorted(result.items(), key = lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)


for k in result.keys():
    print result[k]
```

Comment: *"I think result is really a dic"* - how, given that you've just been told by Python that it's a list, could you possibly still think that?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in function `sorted` takes an iterable as an argument and returns **a list**

You'll need some further conversion to get a dict, which has an attribute `keys` to avoid that exception

```
result = sorted(result.items(), key = lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
# result is now a list, check it with "print type(result)"
for k in result.keys(): # trying to access list's keys, which is not a thing
```

But turning it into a dict is not what you want. Instead, since `sorted(result.items())` became a list of dict's items in a sorted order, you don't need to iterate through the dict's keys to get the items. Do something like that after the `result = sorted..` line:

```
for i in result:
    print i
```

Comment: exactly, 
print type(result)


for k in result:
 print k[0] + str(k[1])